# Can I play on a non-steam servers like PGN from my original Steam Counter Strike: Condition zero?

Tags: steam, counter-strike

I am thinking of buying original Counter Strike: Condition Zero with steam because my points resets when I re-install my Windows. Is it possible to play on non-steam servers like PGN from my original Steam CS: Condition Zero?

Comment: You can register CS:CZ's CD key with Steam to add it to your Steam account.  Create a steam account first if you don't already have one.

Comment: Having said that, in this day and ago, non-Steam servers usually imply that they're pirate servers, as CS 1.6 and CS:CZ have been on Steam for 8 years.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing Counter-Strike 1.6 for many years, and as far as I know, the server-client principle is the same as in Condition Zero (I own CZ too).
All you need to do in order to play on a server of your choosing, is to make sure that the server you want to play on is updated to the latest version in order to be compatible with the Steam game client (which is, of course, automatically updated by Valve to the latest version). The best way is to ask the server owner. If your favorite server is using outdated CZ server files, then you won't be able to play (until the owner updates it).
If the server is updated to the latest version, just add the server IP into favorites in Condition Zero server browser and play.